# Can we draw 3D/2D objects in PyQt5 just like we do in Processing?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I was wondering if we could create 3D objects in PyQt5 just like we do in Processing using Java or can we create 2D squares/arcs/circles just like we do in Tkinter.

Actually I am shifting from processing to PyQt5 for my project which involves MEMS Gyro and Accelerometer. And I would like to do the same visualization in PyQt5 as well. 
So far I am fine with other features of PyQt5 like Button, Entries etc but could not find anything for 3D or 2D visualization.

Any kind of reference to documentation,advice based on personal experience will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, there is a sperate class in Qt for such kind of painting stuff. This class is called QPainter. You can also use Pyqtgraph along with Opengl. 
This may help.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html

[Plot cube using pyqtgraph in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53136301/plot-cube-using-pyqtgraph-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can consider of [Glass Engine](https://pypi.org/project/glass-engine/). It not supports PyQt5 but supports PyQt6. It can easily add interactive 3D viewport into anywhere of your PyQt6 program. You can add basic geometries or load model from file. To install it, just use `pip install glass-engine`.

See full document of Glass Engine at https://glass-engine-doc.readthedocs.io/zh/latest/